# SAS Proc copy overwrite password protected file

Tags: sas, passwords

I am trying to use PROC COPY to overwrite an existing, password protected table.  I keep getting an error message saying 'Invalid or missing ALTER password on member [destination file]'.

I am trying to run the following sort of code:

```
PROC COPY OUT=dest IN=source alter=password;
select data;
run;
```

The problem lies with the alter=statement.  I've moved it to different part of the statement, but just cannot get the code to accept the password so that it can overwrite the datatset.

Thanks for any help.

Note: I do not want to simply use a data set statement, because the file being copied has an associated index which I also want copied.

Comment: Does the dataset DEST.DATA already exist?   Is the dataset SOURCE.DATA using a different (or no) password than DEST.DATA?  If yes to both then delete DEST.DATA first.

Answer (score 1):

the following example copies the data with index and password:

```
options dlcreatedir;
libname L1 "%sysfunc(pathname(WORK))/test1";
libname L2 "%sysfunc(pathname(WORK))/test2";

data L1.test(index=(make) pw=abc12345);
  set sashelp.cars;
run;

PROC COPY OUT=L2 IN=L1 alter=abc12345;
select test;
run;
```

the log:

```
1    options dlcreatedir;
2    libname L1 "%sysfunc(pathname(WORK))/test1";
NOTE: Library L1 was created.
NOTE: Libref L1 was successfully assigned as follows:
      Engine:        V9
      Physical Name: ********************\test1
3    libname L2 "%sysfunc(pathname(WORK))/test2";
NOTE: Libref L2 was successfully assigned as follows:
      Engine:        V9
      Physical Name: ********************\test2
4
5    data L1.test(index=(make) pw=XXXXXXXX);
6      set sashelp.cars;
7    run;

NOTE: There were 428 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CARS.
NOTE: The data set L1.TEST has 428 observations and 15 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


8
9    PROC COPY OUT=L2 IN=L1 alter=XXXXXXXX;
10   select test;
11   run;

NOTE: Copying L1.TEST to L2.TEST (memtype=DATA).
NOTE: Simple index Make has been defined.
NOTE: There were 428 observations read from the data set L1.TEST.
NOTE: The data set L2.TEST has 428 observations and 15 variables.
NOTE: PROCEDURE COPY used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

Comment: You haven't tried to copy over an existing password protected data set.  Instead your code is copying from a password protected data set.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a case of the documentation not aligning with reality.

This version (based on @yabwon) will copy over, but in interactive SAS, requires me to type in the password into a dialog box.  In batch mode would probably just fail.

```
options dlcreatedir;
libname SRC "%sysfunc(pathname(WORK))/test1";
libname DST "%sysfunc(pathname(WORK))/test2";

data DST.cars(pw=abc12345);
  set sashelp.cars;
run;

data SRC.cars;
  set sashelp.cars;
run;
data SRC.class;
  set sashelp.class;
run;

PROC COPY IN=SRC OUT=DST alter=abc12345 ;
select cars ;
run;
```

None of these variants work either `select cars(alter=...)` `select cars/alter=...`

[image]

Comment: Are you saying the presence of a dataset that does NOT have a password causes the copy to fail?  Or are you saying that the presence of an existing dataset that needs to be replaced causes it to fail?  What happens if you DELETE the existing dataset before copying in the new dataset?

Comment: Replacing the protected file fails programmatically.  To copy 'over' you would need to delete with password, proc copy and then apply password to new version of destination.  I'm not sure when the purpose of the `alter=` option is at this point, or if it has become non-functional overtime.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my experience Richard. One other solution I figured is that I can remove the password protection from the dataset, overwrite the dataset, then reapply the password.

Answer (score 0):

Just be consistent in your use of ALTER passwords for the datasets.

- It works fine when the target dataset does not yet exist.
- It works fine when the new and old dataset both use the same password.

So take one of these two actions.

- Make the dataset you are copying using the same password, before you try to copy it.
- Remove the existing dataset (using PROC DELETE for example) before copying in the new dataset.